# Why can I not see the execution of my sorting algorithm using SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am running SDL2 on a macOS and am struggling to display the changing state of my sorting algorithm. I get an already completed sort. The code structure I believe to be causing the issue looks something like this:

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        for(unsigned int j = i; j < v.size(); j++){

            if(v[j] < v[i]){
                std::swap(v[j],v[i]);
            }
            //Clear Screen
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            //Draw Sort State
            draw_state(v, renderer, i, j);
            //Show Window
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            //Event handler
            bool quit = false;
            SDL_Event e;

            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) // poll for event
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) // unless player manually quits
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know that the issue has to do with how I am using the SDL_Event feature. When I run my code, I get an already sorted vector visual. What I actually want is every position in the SDL2 window to display every single change happening in the code as the function runs. Any ideas on how to fix the issue. I am running on a macOS.

**UPDATE:**

After applying all of the fixes mentioned in an answer, my program still does not work. I am still having trouble with the actual visualization of the swapping. It could possibly be my `draw_state` function causing issues. Here is my updated code:

```
void draw_state(std::vector<int>& v, SDL_Renderer* renderer, unsigned int i, unsigned int j){
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer,index,99,index,i);
        index+=1;

    }  
}

void close(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer){
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void sort_algorithm(std::vector<int> &v, SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned int j = i; j < v.size(); j++) {

            if(v[j] < v[i]) {
                std::swap(v[j],v[i]);
            }
            //Clear Screen
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            //Draw Sort State
            draw_state(v, renderer, i, j);
            //Show Window
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) // poll for event
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) // unless player manually quits
                {
                    //break out of nested loop
                    goto break_out_of_nested_loop;
                }
            }

            SDL_Delay( 200 );
        }
    }

    break_out_of_nested_loop:

        close(window, renderer);
}
```

Comment: It's probably happening too fast for you to see each frame. You might add a delay between each step of a few frames.

Comment: I have SDL_Delay(10) outside of the while loops. Should I change the placement of it to some other position? This is my first time using SDL2 so I am new to the proper placement of structures.

Comment: Are you possibly stuck in that while loop? Seems to me like unless you press quit you'll never exit out of it, you should only have one while loop for the events the outer loop will prevent you from doing any other iteration after the first one because unless you press quit you just poll events agii

Comment: Please don't overwrite your original question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. By applying all fixes that I recommended in my answer to the code in your question, you have invalidated my answer. If you want to update your question by showing us updated code, then please leave the original question intact. You can add this updated code to the bottom of the question and mark this as an "UPDATE" or an "EDIT", so that it is clear what your original question was.

Comment: In your function `draw_state`, what is the point of having two loop counters `index` and `i` which both always have the same value in every loop iteration? I suggest that you remove the variable `index` and replace it with `i`.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `sort_algorithm`, the loop `while( !quit )` will iterate until the user wants to quit. However, that it not what you want. I suggest that you remove this loop and if you detect that the user wants to quit, you break out of all nested loops. Also, you should call [`SDL_Delay`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Delay) once per loop iteration of the inner sorting loop (not the event loop).

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned int j = i; j < v.size(); j++) {

            if(v[j] < v[i]) {
                std::swap(v[j],v[i]);
            }
            //Clear Screen
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            //Draw Sort State
            draw_state(v, renderer, i, j);
            //Show Window
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //Handle events on queue
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) // poll for event
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) // unless player manually quits
                {
                    //break out of nested loop
                    goto break_out_of_nested_loop;
                }
            }

            SDL_Delay( 200 );
        }
    }

break_out_of_nested_loop:

    //TODO: shut down program
}
```

Also, the function `draw_state` does not make sense:

```
void draw_state(std::vector<int>& v, SDL_Renderer* renderer, unsigned int i, unsigned int j){
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer,index,99,index,i);
        index+=1;

    }  
}
```

Since `index` and `i` always have the same value in every loop iteration, this is equivalent to the following:

```
void draw_state( std::vector<int>& v, SDL_Renderer* renderer, unsigned int i, unsigned int j ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255,255,255,255 );
        SDL_RenderDrawLine( renderer, i, 99, i, i );
    }  
}
```

You have programmed this function in such a way that what this function draws is only dependent on `v.size()`, but not on the content of the individual vector elements.

What you probably want is to change the line

```
SDL_RenderDrawLine( renderer, i, 99, i, i );
```

to:

```
SDL_RenderDrawLine( renderer, i, 99, i, 99 + v[i] );
```

That way, the length of the lines are actually dependent on the values of the vector elements.

Comment: This helped to properly close the application. But I am still having trouble with the actual visualization of the swapping. It could possibly be my draw_state function causing issues.

Comment: @PwnsKing: I have updated my answer to specify what is wrong in the function `draw_state`.